# Simple approximations for $\operatorname{erf}(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question, error-function

I am looking for some potentially unexpected approximations of $\operatorname{erf}(x)$, by which I mean not a really long series expansion, and something that resembles the correct shape for an arbitrary amount of the real domain. Here are some I have come up with myself:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\tanh(1.182\cdot x) & \text{the constant is a trade-off}\\
\tanh(1.152\cdot x)+\dfrac{e^{-|x-1.5|}\cos(x-1.5)}{20} & \text{smaller error but not symmetrical}\\
\tanh\left(\frac{x|x|}{4}+x\right) & \text{constant not optimised for this yet}
\end{matrix}
$$
I also read [this](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.15018?journalCode=ajp) article which listed a method for assuming solutions of the form:
$$\tanh(f(x))$$
Just like I initially thought. My question is really, does anyone have any surprisingly accurate short approximations for it? Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2012/2012.04466.pdf is an interesting paper

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that brings all new thoughts to me of how methods may change depending on whether you are approximating a real or complex function, and how $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ looks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily build your own approximations using as a basis
$$\text{erf}(x) \sim \sqrt{1-\exp\Big[
-\frac {4x^2} {\pi} P_{n}(x) \Big]}$$ when $P_n(x)$ is the ratio of two polynomials of degree $n$ in $x^2$ or just a polynomial in $x^2$.

These are quite easy to build writing
$$P=-\frac{\pi  \log \left(1-\text{erf}(x)^2\right)}{4 x^2}$$ and developing as as series around $x=0$
$$P=1-\frac{2 (\pi -3) x^2}{3 \pi }+\frac{2 \left(120-60 \pi +7 \pi ^2\right) x^4}{45
   \pi ^2}-\frac{4 \left(-420+280 \pi -56 \pi ^2+3 \pi ^3\right) x^6}{105 \pi
   ^3}+\frac{2 \left(120960-100800 \pi +28560 \pi ^2-3040 \pi ^3+83 \pi ^4\right)
   x^8}{4725 \pi ^4}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ which can easily be transformed into a Padé approximant.

For example
$$P_0(x)=1 \qquad \qquad P_1(x)=\frac {1+\frac{\left(10-\pi ^2\right) }{5 (\pi -3) \pi }x^2 } {1+\frac{\left(120-60 \pi +7 \pi ^2\right) }{15 (\pi -3) \pi }x^2 }$$

To give you an idea, computing the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_0^\infty \left(\text{erf}(x)-\sqrt{1-\exp\Big[
-\frac {4x^2} {\pi} P_{n}(x) \Big]}\right) ^2\,dx  $$ we have
$$\Phi_0=3.23\times 10^{-5}\qquad \Phi_1=3.04\times 10^{-8}\qquad\Phi_2=1.20\times 10^{-10}\qquad\Phi_3=3.97\times 10^{-12}$$

**Edit**

Using the ideas from the linked paper, we could do basically the same expanding
$$\tanh ^{-1}(\text{erf}(x))=\frac{2 x}{\sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{2 (\pi -4) x^3}{3 \pi ^{3/2}}+\frac{\left(96-40 \pi
   +3 \pi ^2\right) x^5}{15 \pi ^{5/2}}+\frac{\left(5760-3360 \pi +532 \pi ^2-15
   \pi ^3\right) x^7}{315 \pi ^{7/2}}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ and use, as another approximation,
$$\text{erf}(x)\sim \tanh \left(\frac{2 x}{\sqrt{\pi }} Q_n(x)\right)$$ and, similar to $P_1(x)$, write
$$Q_1(x)=\frac{1+\frac{128-40 \pi -\pi ^2}{30 (\pi -4) \pi } x^2} {1+\frac{96-40 \pi +3 \pi ^2}{10 (\pi -4) \pi } x^2}$$ which is much better than what is given in the paper.

$$\Psi_1=\int_0^\infty\left(\text{erf}(x)-\tanh \left(\frac{2 x}{\sqrt{\pi }} Q_n(x)\right)\right) ^2 \,dx =2.22\times 10^{-7} $$

Even if the two formalisms look *similar* in terms of accuracy, I would favor the first one because it makes the inversion of the error function easier ; with $P_1(x)$ you just need to solve a quadratic equation in $x^2$ while with $Q_1(x)$ you just need to solve a cubic equation in $x$.

Comparing with Taylor series, the difference between $\text{erf}(x)$ and its approximations is $1.56\times 10^{-4}x^7$ for $P_1(x)$ and $5.916\times 10^{-4}x^7$  for $Q_1(x)$.

Comment: Ahhh I see, I hadn't heard of the Pade approximant before but it seems like an interesting method

Comment: @HenryLee. It is fascinating ! On the search bar, just type *Pade* : 675 entries

Comment: Absolutely, I like how for any order it seems it is more accurate than the equivalent Taylor/Maclaurin series

Comment: @HenryLee. Almost by definition, $P_1(x)$ is better that the series to $O(x^6)$.

Answer (score 1):

I had made a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4794193/909869), and I found experimentally this simple approximation to the $\text{erf}(x)$ function:

$$z(x)=\tanh\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(x+\frac{11}{123}x^3\right)\right)$$

it keeps the difference $|\text{erf}(x)-z(x)|<0.00036$.

Also I compared in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=MaxValue%5B%7C%5B1%2F2*%28erf%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%2B1%29%5D-%5B1%2F2*%28tanh%282%2Fsqrt%28pi%29*%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%2B11%2F123*%28x%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%5E3%29%29%2B1%29%5D%7C%2Cx%5D&lang=en) using $z(x)$ for taking probabilities of the standard Gaussian distribution, and the max mistake looks its below $0.018\%$, quite accurate in my opinion.

The formula is a modification by trial and error so the last fraction $11/123$ surely could be improved. It comes from the series expansion of $\tanh^{-1}(\text{erf}(x))$ shown in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+atanh%28erf%28x%29%29&lang=en), and just the first 2 terms makes already simple approximation than works quite good: $$f(x)=\tanh\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(x+\frac{(4-\pi)x^3}{3\pi}\right)\right)$$

Here you could see them in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2lsu8l6upz).

---

*Added later*

In the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4795990/909869) I found another approximate much better than the previous, a little more complicated but still simpler than many of the approximations displayed on Wikipedia page for the [Error function: Numerical approximations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations):

$$\tanh\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(x+\frac{28}{305}x^3\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{33}}\right)\right)\to \text{max error}=0.0000551322$$

Again, be aware the constants were find by trial and error in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vlavj8hshi), there nothing special about them a surely could be improved.

Comment: Do not post the same answer to multiple questions.  If one answer is appropriate for several questions, answer only *one* of those questions, and flag the rest of them as duplicates.

Comment: @XanderHenderson How I do that? Using the "flag" link for moderator's intervention?

Comment: In the flagging menu, it should be possible to flag a question as a duplicate.  This is a standard flag, and requires no moderator intervention.