# Gaussian integral over square domain

Tags: calculus

It is easy to evaluate $ \lim_{\rho \to \infty} \int \int _{S} e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy $ where $S = \{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2 \leq \rho^2 \}$ by using polar coordinates and we know the answer is $\pi$.

Next, we would like to evaluate $ \lim_{R \to \infty} \int \int _{S} e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy $ but this time we will make $S = \{ (x,y) : x \in [-R,R], y \in [-R,R] \}$... Ideally, this should also be $\pi$ as in the previous case... However, I am unable to see an efficient way to calculate it. Any hints would be helpful. thanks!

Comment: Why not to use the error function in cartesian coordinates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I(\rho)=\iint_{S(\rho)} e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy$ where $S(\rho)=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le\rho^2\}$. You calculated that $\lim_{\rho\to\infty}I(\rho)=\pi$.

Now, let $T(R)=[-R,R]\times[-R,R]$, and $J(R)=\iint_{T(R)}e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy$. We want $\lim_{R\to\infty} J(R)$.

The key observation here is that $S(\rho)\subseteq T(\rho)\subseteq S(\sqrt2\rho)$, so since $e^{-x^2-y^2}$ is always positive, we have $I(\rho)\le J(\rho)\le I(\sqrt2\rho)$. Now, taking the limit as $\rho\to\infty$, since both $I(\rho)$ and $T(\sqrt2\rho)$ converge to $\pi$, by the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) we must also have $J(\rho)\to\pi$.

---

Graphically, this looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you call the integral you are evaluating $I_R$, then
$$I_R= \left(\int_{-R}^R e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2= 4 \left(\int_0^R e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2$$
and since the function $g(x):=e^{-x^2}$ doesn't have an elementary primitive, I'm afraid this can't be expressed in a simplier way unless you can use special functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept the use of the error function, then
$$I_R=\pi \, \text{erf}(R)^2$$

If you look at my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203484/simple-approximations-for-operatornameerfx/4203740#4203740), you will find quite good approximations
$$\text{erf}(R) \sim \sqrt{1-\exp\Big[-\frac {4R^2} {\pi} P_{n}(R) \Big]}$$ making
$$I_R \sim J_{R,n}=\pi \Bigg[1-\exp\Big[-\frac {4R^2} {\pi} P_{n}(R) \Big] \Bigg]$$

Just to give you an idea
$$\int_0^\infty \Big[I_R-J_{R,0}\Big]^2\,dR=1.01\times 10^{-3}$$
$$\int_0^\infty \Big[I_R-J_{R,1}\Big]^2\,dR=1.14\times 10^{-6}$$