# Approximating the curve of a row of pascal's triangle using a bell curve equation

Tags: approximation, curves

When pascal's triangle extends to all real numbers (i.e., each factorial in the formula $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is extended to all real numbers, making the formula continuous), graphing the formula $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ with any given positive $n$ yields a curve that resembles a bell curve. [For instance, this is what it looks like when $n$ is 4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR7jS.png) So my question is, how could I construct a bell curve formula that could approximate (or fit exactly, if it exists) any curve yielded by $n$?

Comment: Cf. [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 2):

You asked

> So my question is, how could I construct a bell curve formula that could approximate (or fit exactly, if it exists) any curve yielded by n?

Part of the answer is given in the Wikipedia article on
[Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation). This
distribution is defined by
$\,\Pr(k;n,p) = \Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.\,$
When $\,p=\frac12\,$ this is a constant multiple of the
binomial coefficients. The section on normal approximation states

> If $\,n\,$ is large enough, then the skew of the distribution is not too great. In this case a reasonable approximation to
> $\,B(n, p)\,$ is given by the normal distribution
> $${\mathcal {N}}(np,\,np(1-p)),$$

which yields the bell curve shape approximation in a precise way.

Use the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) formula
$$\frac1{\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)} = \frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi z}, $$
to get
$\,{0 \choose  x}=\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x},\,$ ${1 \choose  x}=\frac{1!}{(1-x)}\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x},\,$ ${2 \choose  x}=\frac{2!}{(1-x)(2-x)}\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x},\,$ ${3 \choose  x}=\frac{3!}{(1-x)(2-x)(3-x)}\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x},\,$ etc.
The graph of these functions is similar to a bell curve except
that they have an infinite number of zero values and have
negative values between zero pairs. However, this is a natural
behavior required by the fact that they agree with the binomial
coefficients exactly at all integer values of $\,x.$

Note that $\,\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}\,$ is the normalized
[sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Note the division by zero in the analytical formula
denominators for $\,{n \choose  z}\,$ when $\,z=k=0,1,\dots,n\,$
but the limit exists and is equal to
$\,{n \choose  k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\,$ as expected.

Comment: It's a nice, exact formulation without any special functions when $x$ is not an integer. But it feels a bit circular when $x$ is an integer, since the only role of the sinc in this scenario is $\lim_{x \to k} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi(k-x)}=(-1)^{k-1}$.

Comment: @Ian The limit you wrote is true, but I don't know how this makes it circular. As I wrote, the limit is as expected.

Comment: I mean it doesn't really explain it being a bell curve. It just rewrites the formula for the binomial coefficient. It is definitely useful in the continuous case, though.

Comment: @Ian Oh, I see. Will mention something about that. Thanks for that comment!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Ian's answer, we have two approximations
$$f(n,k)=2^n \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}} e^{-2\frac{ \left(k-\frac{n}{2}\right)^2}{n}}$$
$$g(n,k)=2^n \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}}\int_{k-\frac 12}^{k+\frac 12}e^{-2\frac{ \left(x-\frac{n}{2}\right)^2}{n}}\,dx=2^{n-1} \Bigg[\text{erf}\left(\frac{n-2 k+1}{
   \sqrt{2n}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{n-2 k-1}{
   \sqrt{2n}}\right)\Bigg]$$

Comparing at $k=\frac n2$, some values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & f\left(n,\frac{n}{2}\right) & g\left(n,\frac{n}{2}\right) & \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\\
 2 & 2.25676 & 2.08200 & 2 \\
 4 & 6.38308 & 6.12680 & 6 \\
 6 & 20.8470 & 20.2822 & 20 \\
 8 & 72.2163 & 70.7396 & 70 \\
 10 & 258.369 & 254.126 & 252 \\
 12 & 943.429 & 930.488 & 924 \\
 14 & 3493.78 & 3452.63 & 3432 \\
 16 & 13072.5 & 12937.6 & 12870 \\
 18 & 49299.6 & 48846.9 & 48620 \\
 20 & 187079.0 & 185532.0 & 184756
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you cannot use the error function, use some quite good approximations (have a look at my naswer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203484/simple-approximations-for-operatornameerfx/4203740#4203740)).

Answer (score 0):

The discrete case at least can be regarded as an instance of the central limit theorem: the binomial($n,1/2$) distribution for large $n$ has its PMF given by ${n \choose k} (1/2)^n$ and the normal approximation of that has a PDF given by $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}} e^{-2\frac{(x-n/2)^2}{n}}$. Therefore ${n \choose k}$ as a function of $k$ behaves roughly like $2^n \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}} e^{-2\frac{(k-n/2)^2}{n}}$ if $n$ is large enough. The approximation is improved if you use $\int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2} 2^n \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}} e^{-2\frac{(x-n/2)^2}{n}} \, dx$ instead, especially if $n$ is not extremely huge.

The fact that the interaction with the Gamma function as the interpolant of the factorial plays nice with this is not totally obvious; it is probably easier to replace the factorials with Gamma functions directly instead.