# Analytic form of an ROC curve

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-inference, parametric

I'm studying the problem of combining two sensors for anomaly detection. I want to analyze its performance by the ROC curve. Now I have obtained a parametric equation about the ROC curve:

$$(x,y) = (FPR,TPR) = (\Phi(c(a-t)), \Phi(c(b-t)))$$

where $a,b,c$ are non-negative real numbers, $t$ is the threshold of the anomaly detection method, and $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a standard normal distribution.

Is it possible to analytically express the ROC curve in a function form like $y=f(x)$?

I have drawn the ROC curve (see figure). It seems like an exponential function (maybe $y=x^\alpha$ ?), but I still have no idea whether it is possible to get an analytic form of $f$.
[image]

Comment: Coulf you give me the values of $(a,b,c)$ you used for the plot ? Thanks & cheers. :-)

Comment: I used $(a,b,c)=(0,1,\sqrt{2})$ to plot the figure.

Comment: When you send a comment to a user, add *@user_name* in the text. I think that, being a new user, you did not know. Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Thanks for your friendly reminder!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Thanks for your response and helpful information.

Comment: You are more than welcome. I am always glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$x=\Phi(c(a-t))=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{c
   (a-t)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
$$y=\Phi(c(b-t))=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{c
   (b-t)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
So,
$$t=a-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{c}\, \text{erf}^{-1}(2 x-1)$$ and then
$$y=\frac 12 \Bigg[1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{c (b-a)}{\sqrt{2}}+\text{erf}^{-1}(2
   x-1)\right) \Bigg]$$ From a formal point of view, it is done.

From a practical point of view, you need now to find a "simple" approximation of the inverse of the error function.

If you look at my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203484/simple-approximations-for-operatornameerfx/4203740#4203740), you will find approximations of the error function which can easily be inversed. Using $P_1(x)$, it is at the price of a quadratic equation; it is just immediate with $P_0$ (which could be sufficient).

Otherwise, you can use the series represntations given [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/06/ShowAll.html).

Simple would be
$$ \text{erf}^{-1}(z)=u+\frac{1}{3}u^3+\frac{7 }{30}u^5+\frac{127 }{630}u^7+\frac{4369
  }{22680} u^9+O\left(u^{11}\right)$$ where $u=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2}z$

**Edit**

Starting from the series, a quite good approximation could be obtained with the $[5,4]$ Padé approximant
$$ \text{erf}^{-1}(z)=u\,\frac{1-\alpha_, u^2+\beta\, u^4 } { 1-\gamma\, u^2+\delta\, u^4}\qquad \text{with}\qquad u=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2}z$$ whose error is $\frac{u^{11}}{250}$.

The required coefficients are
$$\alpha=\frac{4397}{4338}\qquad \beta=\frac{111547}{910980} \qquad \gamma=\frac{5843}{4338} \qquad \delta=\frac{20533}{60732}$$ The absolute error is less than $0.01$ as long as $z \leq 0.90$.

**Worked example**

Using for $(a,b,c)$ the values used to generate the plot in the post, that is to say $(0,1,\sqrt{2})$ and all the elements given in this answer, the absolute error on $y$ is smaller than $0.001$ as soon as $x>0.0854215$.

To give an idea : using the norm
$$\Psi(a)=\frac 14\int_a^1\Bigg[\text{erf}\left(1-\text{erf}^{-1}(1-2
   x)\right)-\text{erf}\left(\text{approximation} \right)\Bigg]^2\,dx$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & \Psi(a) \\
 0.00 & 1.24386\times 10^{-4} \\
 0.01 & 2.50636\times 10^{-5} \\
 0.02 & 7.26261\times 10^{-6} \\
 0.03 & 2.37431\times 10^{-6} \\
 0.04 & 8.33009\times 10^{-7} \\
 0.05 & 3.06603\times 10^{-7} \\
 0.06 & 1.16904\times 10^{-7} \\
 0.07 & 4.58574\times 10^{-8} \\
 0.08 & 1.84804\times 10^{-8} \\
 0.09 & 7.70450\times 10^{-9} \\
 0.10 & 3.39594\times 10^{-9} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Hi Claude ! I just saw your answer while i was typing mine. You beat me to the punch. Chears! Bytheway I wonder if my approximate can be justified.

Comment: @JJacquelin. No idea but this is nice.

Comment: Many thanks! This gives me some new points of view about dealing with the error function.
Moreover, it helps me figure out that a good approximation of the error function with a bound will be sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

I doudt that a sufficiently simple analytic function $y=f(x)$ could be found.

Possibly one could approach it with series.

I propose an empirical model on the form of supercircle (particular case of superelipse : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse ).
$$\boxed{(1-x)^c+y^c=1}$$
$$y=\left(1-(1-x)^c \right)^{1/c}$$

[image]

The blue curve is the copy of the graph from your question.

The red curve is the approximation with $c=2.5$

The approximate value of $c$ was computed as folows :

- Scanning your graph for the coordinates of the blue pixels ( 2618 points).
- nonlinear regression for fitting of the function and value of $c$.

Surprisingly the computed value obtained  of $c$ is very close to 2.5

Comment: Thanks! It seems like a very nice approximation.

Comment: Also, I added the info about the figure in the comment below the original question.