# A better approximation of 0.5erfc(x)

Tags: normal-distribution

Here, after using some transform I have been working on, I got this:

$$y(x) = \frac{(\sigma x + \mu) \cdot ((\sigma x + \mu) + 6) \cdot (1 - e^{-6 (\sigma x + \mu)})}{\sqrt{2 \pi (\sigma x + \mu)}}$$

Simply put, it effectively becomes really close $erfc(x)/2$ after almost  $x=\mu+2\sigma/3$ to a level that is very useful to any application and its calculation cost is very small.
But before $x=\mu+2\sigma/3$ its less accurate, as it starts with an error of almost 20% at $x=\mu$  but the rapidly vanishes, so the question is how to make it more accurate for $x<\mu+2\sigma/3$?.

Edit 1:
this was the original approximation:

$$1-\exp(-6x)\cdot\frac{x(x+6)}{\sqrt{2\pi x}} = 1-\frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}(x)\\$$

$$\text{erfc}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$$

LHS=RHS when x>≈4.95909030730313

Comment: First, it is more effective and comprehensible if you express your approximation as $\mathrm{erfc}(x) \approx \dots$. Then, you can compare your approximation with the literature, see for example [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.24) as a starting point.

Comment: It is also interesting to compare with the inequalities from [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.8).

Comment: See Vedder's article: Vedder, J. D. (1987). Simple approximations for the error function and its inverse. American Journal of Physics, 55(8), 762–763. doi:10.1119/1.15018 . He uses the approximation: $$\rm{erf}(x) =  \tanh (\frac{167}{148} x + \frac {11}{109} x^3)$$.

Comment: so I will be expressing in terms erfc(x) for x ranges

Comment: The tanh function seems a bit different but its pretty accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have good approximations of the error function, in the same spirit as Vedder, you can write
$$\text{erf}(x)\sim \tanh \left(\sum _{i=1}^n a_i\, x^{2 i-1}\right)$$ and, using Taylor expansions of both sides around $x=0$, identify the coefficients.

This would give
$$a_1=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\qquad a_2=\frac{2 (4-\pi )}{3 \pi ^{3/2}} \qquad a_3=   \frac{96-40 \pi +3 \pi ^2}{15 \pi ^{5/2}}$$
$$a_4=\frac{5760-3360 \pi +532 \pi ^2-15 \pi ^3}{315 \pi ^{7/2}}$$

Looking at the error, its maximum value is $3.37\times 10^{-5}$ for $x=2.42$.

If you consider the norm for $n=4$
$$\Phi=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Bigg(\text{erf}(x)- \tanh \left(\sum _{i=1}^4 a_i\, x^{2 i-1}\right)\Bigg)^2\,dx=1.55\times 10^{-9}$$

Notice that $\frac{167}{148}$ and $\frac{11}{107}$ are rational approximations of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

If you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203484/simple-approximations-for-operatornameerfx/4203740#4203740), you will find other good approximations. Using $P_1(x)$ allows to invert the function at the price of a quadratic equation in $x^2$.